# How can I use Topics in a GitLab project's general settings?

Tags: gitlab

The GitLab documentation about Topics is not very informative because it doesn't say what it is used for or how I can use it to my advantage.

[image]
Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/

**Got any tips?**

I was hoping I could use it to bookmark a "category" of projects within my group by adding something like this to the end of the URL "?topics=MyCategory", but I couldn't hack it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Topics can be used to group certain repos which are not necessarily in the same group, e.g. if you have one repo containing infrastructure code in different groups you can mark them all with the same topic and see which infrastructure repos you have.

You can list all repos with `your_topic`  with https://your-gitlab-url-com/explore/projects?tag=your_topic, or click on the topic icon in the repo overview.

Comment: Thank you.  Any idea where that is documented?

Comment: Same question: is there some basic documentation on the subject of  GitLab 'topics' I am overlooking? (I wanted to get information if we can use several topics for any project, and thus be able to flatten the hierarchy of GitLab project groups while maintaining the ability to find related projects.) All I can find is third-party information, like: "Topics can be used to categorize projects and find similar new projects." (via the python-gitlab library documentation, e.g.)